How to make save DuckDbConnection in ASP.NET Core app if API reads data while background worker writes data to the same .db file?
DuckDbConnection can be open only once per .db file. So I have the connection as a singleton. My service has got a lot of unmanaged memory. At some point, I must dispose the connection.
What is the best way to do it thread safely?
I recreate DuckDbConnection connection at midnight with timer.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
